# Powering Raspberry Pi 3 alternatives

Tags: usb, power, power-supply, power-management, alternative-power

I am starting my first raspberry pie project and I am essentially going for a entertainment center. I ordered a 2.5A power adapter to provide power to the unit, but was wondering if it was possible to power the unit using USB or some alternate way. Because the unit will be connected to the TV at all times, I would like to minimize on the number connections to the wall for power - if at all possible. Will this require a separate set up / installation / any special hardware?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You **may** be able to power a Pi3 from a USB port, but it is not recommended. The USB 2 standard specifies an output current of 0.5 Amp (USB3 can supply up to 1 Amp), well below the recommend rating for the Pi. This can lead to a variety of hard to track down issues (e.g. freezing of the Pi, SD card corruption, networking issues), a quick search of this site will turn up several more issues resulting from an insufficient power supply.

You could use a battery pack to power the Pi, but that does not really solve the problem as the battery will need to be recharged somehow, and is likely to lead to a subpar user experience when the battery dies mid movie or game.

One alternative may be to purchase a power bar (that has high Amp USB charging ports built in - these typically supply > 2.0 Amps) like this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DM0BP2G)

[image: Power Bar with charging ports]

(Note: these come in a variety of socket and charging port configurations. This specific model only has 2 USB Ports that supply 2 Amps). This would only use one wall socket and supply sufficient current to safely power your Pi.

Answer (score 0):

PoE, with a PoE switch and a PoE splitter at the pi end. One simple network cable coming into the back of the tv.